# Ionic doesn't create a project

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a problem and I don't know how solve it. 
I can not create an ionic project. Uninstalled all: node, angular-cli, ionic, etc. And reinstalled it but the same error continues (windows and macos):

I don't understand this error, I don't have install any certificate

node -v 
**v6.11.3**

ionic -v
**3.12.0**

angular-cli: **1.4.4**
node: **6.11.3**
os: **win32 x64**

Anyone know how to fix it ??

Thanks

```
ionic start test blank
√ Creating directory .\test - done!
[INFO] Fetching app base (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.tar.gz)
× Downloading - failed!
Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "Host: codeload.github.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.akamaized.net, DNS:*.akamaihd-staging.net, DNS:*.akamaized-staging.net, DNS:*.akamaihd.net, DNS:a248.e.akamai.net"
at Object.checkServerIdentity (tls.js:199:17)
at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1098:29)
at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:610:8)
at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:440:38)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
The problem was my internet provider that block some dns and block my ip.

Thanks